# Mapping/matching toys with children

Tags: algorithm, machine-learning, data-structures, deep-learning, matching

Is there any algorithm that works to find the best match

For eg

Let's say we have 100 toys and 100 children 
We want the toys to get matched with childrens considering every child and every toy have their own specific characterstics which we can call as features, like toy can have features like [shape, size, color.....]
and each children have preferences like [color_pref, fav_character_pref......]

Now is there a way, I can map a toy to one children considering one-to-one mapping and supposedly mapped kth toy is the best match for jth children i.e.. as per his preferences kth toy is best.

My initial thought is to use Gale–Shapley algorithm.

Could machine learning be used here ?

Answer (score 1):

While the question explicitly asks for a machine learning solution, note that apparently the problem can be modeled as a [weighted bipartite matching](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matching_(graph_theory)) problem, the partitions being the children and the toys while the weight would be the number of satisfied preferences. This problem can be solved using the so-called [Hungarian algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hungarian_algorithm) within a polynomial runtime bound.

Comment: Thanks. I have a doubt here @Codor !!

if children pref vector also have words spoken by children like `I love pokemon`, how do i model this specific feature/preference as well along with other features in children's pref vector which could be colors for eg: ['i love pokemon', 'yellow', '1.3ft'] on the lines of bipartite matching ?

Comment: As I have indicated in the comment to the answer by Paddy3118, the generation of the preference value based on the child's expression and the feature description of the toys seems to be a problem that is separate from the actual assignment problem.

Answer (score 0):

Think of toys as boys and children as girls, then if every child ranks their preference for all the toys then your problem maps to the [Stable Marriage](http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Stable_marriage_problem) problem/solution

Comment: No. it's not that straight.
Children have preferences like these `['i love pokemon', 'yellow', '1.3ft']` and similarily toys have features like these `['pikachu', 'yellow', '1.2ft']`

Prefernces are not as straight as always in stable marriage problem.
Please correct me if I am wrong

Comment: You might weight each toy according to the weight each child puts on a set of features and the toy having that feature to get the ordering ...

Comment: It seems as if the modeled optimization problem (which is bipartite matching, stable marriage, generalized assignment problem - whatever you might call it) is to be seen in its real-world context. It is not a reasonable assumption that a child is able to express him- or herself in terms of a 'preference value'. Of course, this depends on the child and the age of the child, but I woul not rely on it.

Comment: @Codor child is just a placeholder, what if i tell you matching has to be done b/w MAN and WOMEN